# protect_from_forgery :exception vs :reset_session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We have app where we often get *InvalidAuthenticity* token as we have setup session timeout in 30 minutes.

I would like using `reset_session` instead of `exception`.

My question is is there any trade off using `reset_session` instead of `exception`.